# CA2000: Dispose objects before losing scope

Tags: vb.net, winforms, code-analysis

I'm getting the error in  this part of code when I try to run the code analysis in my project.

//Code

```
  Private Sub SaveMaterialStatus(ByVal status As String)

        Dim cSMaterialInput As CSMaterialInput = Nothing

        Try

            If ViewState("CSInput") IsNot Nothing Then
                'Create a new transaction
                cSMaterialInput = New CSMaterialInput
                cSMaterialInput = ViewState("CSInput")
                cSMaterialInput.CSStatus = status
                CSMaterialInputMethods.SaveToDatabase(cSMaterialInput, Environment.UserName, Environment.MachineName)

            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw

        Finally
            If cSMaterialInput IsNot Nothing Then cSMaterialInput.Dispose()

        End Try
    End Sub
```

Detailed Error:

```
CA2000  Dispose objects before losing scope In method 'ShowSummary.SaveMaterialStatus(String)', call System.IDisposable.Dispose on object 'cSMaterialInput' before all references to it are out of scope.   xxxx.CostingTool.Presentation   ShowSummary.aspx.vb 790
```

Where i'm wrong??

Comment: Your code is borken.  You have **two** assignments to cSMaterialInput.  The first one does nothing, the second one almost certainly should *not* be disposed.

Comment: @HansPassant: So what can I do now? Can to post the correct code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 cSMaterialInput = New CSMaterialInput
```

That's where the problem started.  You immediately reassign the variable in the next statement so the object you created never gets disposed.  Which triggered the CA2000 warning.  There is just no point to creating a new object that you never use.  Which leaves little else in the method:

```
  Private Sub SaveMaterialStatus(ByVal status As String)
      Dim cSMaterialInput = ViewState("CSInput")
      If cSMaterialInput IsNot Nothing Then
          cSMaterialInput.CSStatus = status
          CSMaterialInputMethods.SaveToDatabase(cSMaterialInput, Environment.UserName, Environment.MachineName)
      End If
  End Sub
```

With the Nothing test still a significant code smell.  It is just hiding a bug when your program tries to save *nothing*.